# Distributing Apps other than App Store

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store

Lets say I want to write an app for a company that helps with keeping their papers, policies, or whatever in digital form This app would need to be internal to that particular company as those documents do not need to be released to the world. The company could be big or small, so anywhere for 10 devices to like 10,000 devices. I would I create the app as for that company as freelancer or an outside agent. How would I be able to allow the company use that app without putting it up on the App Store or making it open to the public.

I Tried all the solutions available in the internet however i could not install it, the only solution that worked is using the JailBreak, however not all users are using Jailbreak.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to be an enterprise developer to be able to distribute In-House. -> https://developer.apple.com/programs/enterprise/